# Using a deprecated perl script to run diogenes, how can i rewrite this code for newer versions?

Tags: perl

I've searched a couple of topics about this issue, and in the exact same context (running diogenes on linux) on the following link, but it was closed due to vagueness in the submission:

[Running old perl script (2007)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40609960/running-old-perl-script-2007/40610611#40610611)

So, the error message is this:

```
Can't use 'defined(@array)' (Maybe you should just omit the defined()?) at /usr/local/diogenes/perl/CPAN/CGI.pm line 449.
Compilation failed in require at ./diogenes-server.pl line 42.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./diogenes-server.pl line 42.
```

At line 449 in CGI.pm there is this:

```
   if (defined(@QUERY_PARAM) && !defined($initializer)) {
```

So reading up a bit, it seems that this code is wrong and it has been deprecated in newer version of perl. Being Diogenes such an old software it seems correct. So, how can I rewrite this in order to move on.

Lastly, i am following this tutorial on how to run diogenes on linux and have no clue about perl programming:
http://community.dur.ac.uk/p.j.heslin/Software/Diogenes/linux_install.php.

:)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Perl error, cant use defined(@array). How can i fix this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52708109/perl-error-cant-use-definedarray-how-can-i-fix-this)

Answer (score 4):

The problem isn't really Diogenes itself. The problem is that Diogenes has packaged up all of the CPAN modules that it uses and that includes a version of CGI.pm from 2004.

That wouldn't be a problem, except that you're running this on a far newer version of Perl - Perl 5.22 or greater. The [perldelta for Perl 5.22](https://metacpan.org/pod/distribution/perl/pod/perl5220delta.pod) includes this:

> **defined(@array) and defined(%hash) are now fatal errors**
>
> These have been deprecated since v5.6.1 and have raised deprecation warnings since v5.16.

So what's happening here is:

- Diogenes includes a really old version of CGI.pm which uses deprecated syntax.
- Diogenes doesn't include a version of the Perl compiler.
- You are now using a version of Perl which has turned this deprecated syntax warning into a fatal error.

It looks like you have three options:

- Downgrade to an earlier version of Perl (pre-5.22) which will just warn on this syntax.
- Remove the Diogenes-installed copy of CGI.pm and install a recent version of CGI.pm from CPAN (version 3.60, released in 2012, fixed this bug).
- Hack your Diogenes-installed copy of CGI.pm to replace `defined(@QUERY_PARAM)` with just `@QUERY_PARAM`.

In a comment, you mention trying the last suggestion on my list and getting a different problem. It looks like that's also caused by changes in Perl syntax (this time, regex syntax) in the twelve years since Diogenes was last updated. And, of course, it's possible that fixing that will just reveal another, similar, problem.

All in all, it might be worth contacting the author of Diogenes and explaining the problems you're having using the software with modern versions of Perl. Even if the author doesn't have time to fix the problems, it's possible that they could add a warning to the web site, telling people about these problems.

Answer (score 3):

As documented in [`defined`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/defined.html) (and mentioned in the error message), try changing this:

```
if (defined(@QUERY_PARAM) && !defined($initializer)) {
```

into this:

```
if (@QUERY_PARAM && !defined($initializer)) {
```

Comment: This comes up:
    <h1>Software error:</h1>
    <pre>Unescaped left brace in regex is illegal here in regex; marked by &lt;-- HERE 
    in m/xxbeginsamepage(?:\n\\nrm{ &lt;-- HERE } \n)?/ at 
    /usr/local/diogenes/perl/Diogenes/Base.pm line 2769.
    Compilation failed in require at ./diogenes-server.pl line 52.
    BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at ./diogenes-server.pl line 52.

Comment: That's a different issue/question. Try putting a backslash \ in front of the `{` that it is complaining about.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.  This is what comes up now and a buch of other stuff that doesnt' fir in a reply. Should I start a new post?

Comment: In `Diogenes/Base.pm`, on line 2769 through 2792, there are several `s#SSS#RRR#` expressions. In the `SSS` parts, change any `{` into `\{`. If that still doesn't help, then yes, post a new question. *Update:* Sorry, I was mistaken - it's only that one expression on line 2769 that is an issue, `nrm{}` should be changed to `nrm\{}`.

Comment: That did it! Thank you. This started the server and gave me a url, but doesn't work. Guess its for another topic.

Answer (score -3):

Try changing it to `exists`.

This also works if the purpose is to test for non-emptiness:

`if (@QUERY_PARAM && !$initializer) {`

Comment: `if` without parens looks like Perl 6, not Perl 5 syntax. Also, `!$initializer` is not the same as `!defined($initializer)`. And `exists` doesn't make sense here either.